# ValueError: X has 1 features, but LogisticRegression is expecting 30 features as input

Tags: python, numpy, flask, scikit-learn, ngrok

I am trying to deploy a machine learning model using flask and ngrok. I have very little knowledge about everything that I'm using and trying so bear with me.
The page takes in 30 inputs as features and then those inputs are used in the model to do the prediction. In the notebook, the input is taken as a tuple followed by turning it to a numpy array and reshaping it to enter into the model, and it works fine there. But in the deployed version, from what I understand the inputs from the form come in the form of a list, so turning that list to a tuple followed by the steps that I did before should have made it work but I keep getting an error message that the model is expecting 30 features but X has 1.

I'm running everything on google colab. The flask part of the code is-

```
import flask
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import pickle
from flask_ngrok import run_with_ngrok
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


app = Flask(__name__)
run_with_ngrok(app)

model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl','rb'))
scaler = pickle.load(open('scaler.pkl', 'rb'))


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    features = [float(x) for x in request.form.values()]
    print(features)
    input_data = tuple(features)
    input_data_as_numpy_array = np.asarray(input_data)
    input_data_reshaped = input_data_as_numpy_array.reshape(1, -1)
    prediction = model.predict(input_data_reshaped)
    print("prediction:",prediction)
    output = round(prediction[0], 2)
    print(output)

    if output == 0:
        return render_template('index.html', prediction_text='THE PATIENT IS MORE LIKELY TO HAVE A BENIGN CANCER WITH PROBABILITY VALUE  {}'.format(y_prob))
    else:
         return render_template('index.html', prediction_text='THE PATIENT IS MORE LIKELY TO HAVE A MALIGNANT CANCER WITH PROBABILITY VALUE  {}'.format(y_prob))

@app.route('/predict_api',methods=['POST'])
def predict_api():

    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    prediction = model.predict([np.array(list(data.values()))])

    output = prediction[0]
    return jsonify(output)

app.run()
```

The error message is-

```
ERROR:__main__:Exception on /predict [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2529, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1825, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1823, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "<ipython-input-41-008535626709>", line 29, in predict
    prediction = model.predict(input_data_reshaped)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py", line 419, in predict
    scores = self.decision_function(X)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py", line 400, in decision_function
    X = self._validate_data(X, accept_sparse="csr", reset=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 588, in _validate_data
    self._check_n_features(X, reset=reset)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 389, in _check_n_features
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: X has 1 features, but LogisticRegression is expecting 30 features as input.
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [23/Nov/2023 04:28:53] "POST /predict HTTP/1.1" 500 -
[0.0]
```

The issue might be something that I've not stated and I might have written something wrong somewhere else, so feel free to correct me.

Comment: What is the shape of `input_data_reshaped`?

Comment: @kiner_shah In the notebook where the model works, the shape of `input_data_reshaped` is (1,30). But I am unable to check it in the flask part as when I run the cell it keeps running and the link comes during that itself.

Comment: I resolved it. I had named all the inputs in the index.html file with the same name, so even after having the required no. of inputs they were all coming in as a single input. Thanks for the help.